# Get the error code from Play Integrity API Exception

Tags: android, exception

I'm implementing the Play Integrity API and in each listener, I want to handle any exceptions.

This is an example that occurs when passing an empty nonce:

```
IntegrityManager integrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());

Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> integrityTokenResponse = integrityManager.requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest.builder().setNonce("").build());
integrityTokenResponse
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<IntegrityTokenResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> task) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "completed");
            if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "!isSuccessful");
                
                Exception e = task.getException();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Outputs:

> completed
>
> !isSuccessful
>
> -10: Integrity API error (-10): Nonce length is too short. The nonce must be a minimum of 16 bytes (before base64 encoding) to allow for better security. Retry with a longer nonce.
>
> (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#NONCE_TOO_SHORT).
>
> failed
>
> -10: Integrity API error (-10): Nonce length is too short. The nonce must be a minimum of 16 bytes (before base64 encoding) to allow for better security. Retry with a longer nonce.
>
> (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#NONCE_TOO_SHORT).

At the [exception url](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#NONCE_TOO_SHORT) `NONCE_TOO_SHORT` corresponds to `-10` as shown in the exception message.

The [official documentation explains the error codes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/error-codes), but how to get that code from the exception/result? (I prefer a way that doesn't extract it from the text of the exception message)

I already looked for some Exception methods like `get*Code` or `getError` or similar, also on the listener task variable but they are not.

Can someone help me (with Java code) please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add below code inside

`.addOnFailureListener { }` of token request

```
val errorMessage = getErrorText(it as IntegrityServiceException)
```

so that it would like this

```
.addOnFailureListener {val errorMessage = getErrorText(it as IntegrityServiceException) }
```

and getErrorText() would be implemented like below

```
private fun getErrorText(it: IntegrityServiceException): String {
    when (it.errorCode) {
        IntegrityErrorCode.API_NOT_AVAILABLE -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.PLAY_STORE_NOT_FOUND -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.NETWORK_ERROR -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.PLAY_STORE_ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.APP_NOT_INSTALLED -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_FOUND -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.APP_UID_MISMATCH -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.CANNOT_BIND_TO_SERVICE -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.NONCE_TOO_SHORT -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.NONCE_TOO_LONG -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.GOOGLE_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.NONCE_IS_NOT_BASE64 -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.PLAY_STORE_VERSION_OUTDATED -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_OUTDATED -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER_IS_INVALID -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.CLIENT_TRANSIENT_ERROR -> return ""
        IntegrityErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR -> return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```

so final code looks like below

```
 IntegrityManagerFactory.create(applicationContext).requestIntegrityToken(
                IntegrityTokenRequest.builder().setNonce(
                    Base64.encodeToString(
                        requestNonce, Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP
                    )
                ).build()
            ).addOnSuccessListener { response1 ->
                //localWay(response, decodedDecryptionKey,decodedVerificationKey)
                //cloudWay(response1)
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                val errorMessage = getErrorText(it as IntegrityServiceException)
            }
```

Comment: Hi, can you post in in Java instead of kotlin please?